# C++ Mongodb driver v2.2 scons install failed on Linux

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost, scons

I have install this driver for a long time, but failed. There is some failed infomation as following

```
# scons
Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt... no
Checking for C++ library boost_thread... no
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib/:/usr/local/mpc/lib:/usr/local/gmp/lib:/usr/local/mpfr/lib/
# ls /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread* -l
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 288364 Dec 28 18:16 /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     40 Jan  1 13:05 /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so -> /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.52.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     25 Dec 28 18:10 /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.52.0
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 186164 Dec 28 18:10 /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.52.0
```

I have installed the boost v1.52, scons v2.2.0, and I want to install the mongodb C++ driver v2.2. Any Ideas? thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable affects where libraries are located at runtime, not at link time. The client driver SConstruct file provides an option `--extrapath`, which allows you to provide additional library search paths.

Try running:

`scons --extrapath=/usr/local`

to see if it will pick up boost libraries that you have installed in /usr/local.

Comment: @yongli I'm glad I was able to help. Would you mind upvoting and accepting my answer since it helped you?.

Comment: Sorry. This is the first time I use stackoverflow asking question, and I'not familiar with this flow. And it was accepted now. Thanks very much.